# Triggering resize of Kendo UI Chart in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kendo-ui, telerik, window-resize

When using **Kendo UI**'s **[Chart component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/charts/series-types/bar/)** in **Vue**, **how to trigger chart redraw / refresh?**

While the chart do adjust to resize width changes by horizontally filling up it's parent container, it's graph and most notably title text (a.k.a. *legend*) and axis labels are stretching, indicating that the chart renders into a SVG image. This stretching is undesirable, so I'm needing to programmatically trigger **resize** / **redraw** / **re-render** as [documented here if using jQuery version of the package](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/methods/resize).

I have resize handler in place using [Vue.resize](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.resize):

```html
<kendo-chart
    ref="chart"
    :series="series"
    v-resize:throttle.500="onResize"
/>
```

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class MyChartComponent extends Vue {
  series = [...]; // some data here

  onResize() {
    // Resize method not found in this scope:
    // this.$refs.chart.resize();

    // Logging chart component to search for the refresh method...
    console.log(this.$refs.chart);
    console.log(this.$refs.chart.kendoWidget());
    // Did not find it there with extensive searching
    // through the objects in browser console.

    // Component's force update works but would be a costly operation:
    // this.$forceUpdate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to access the `resize` method, although not an entirely clean solution:

```js
get chartWidget(): any {
  return (this.$refs.chart as KendoChart).kendoWidget() as any;
}

// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
this.chartWidget._resize();
```

Interested in hearing a better way which would also work with correct types.